# jsp:text losing whitespace inside tagx

Tags: jsp, jetty, whitespace, jsp-tags

Trying to use JSPX and running into a strange problem.  Text inside jsp:text is supposed to not be subject to whitespace removal, according to the JSP documentation, but when I have a jsp:text element with leading whitespace in the beginning of a tagx file, when used in the jspx views, the leading whitespace disappears.

I've done quite a bit of Googling but can't find what's causing this to be removed.  I've verified that the same jsp:text instances included directly in the jspx view work correctly, but put into a separate tagx file causes it to be lost.

This is under Jetty 6.1.19 and 6.1.22 using JSP 2.1 libraries.

**EDIT**: Some sample code follows.  Note that the spaces leading and trailing within the `<jsp:text>` tags are stripped.  Judging by the JSP documentation I can see, whitespace within those should be retained.

WEB-INF/tabs/nameValuePair.tagx:

```
<jsp:root version="2.0" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page">
<jsp:directive.attribute name="name" type="java.lang.String" required="true"/>
<jsp:directive.attribute name="value" type="java.lang.String" required="true"/>
<jsp:text> ${name}=${value} </jsp:text>
</jsp:root>
```

test.jspx:

```
<jsp:root version="2.0" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:t="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags">
<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <t:nameValuePair name="name" value="Google" />
        <t:nameValuePair name="age" value="11" />
        <t:nameValuePair name="description" value="Popular Search Engine" />
        <jsp:text> test=value </jsp:text>
    </body>
</html>

</jsp:root>
```

output:

```
<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body>name=Googleage=11description=Popular Search Engine test=value </body></html>
```

Comment: If you replace the whitespace with dots or something, are they preserved?
Are you sure there is not something else surrounding the tag that removes the whitespace?
Is whitespace outside of the tag removed also or is it only the whitespace of your jsp:text that dissapears?

Comment: Note that the jsp:text tags that are losing their spaces are directly under the jsp:root of the tagx file, and nothing's enclosing them within the jspx file.  Similar jsp:text tags directly inside the jspx file retain their leading and trailing spaces, but the ones inside the tagx file do not.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the issue is. The " test=value " has spaces in the output. The t:nameValuePair items do not have spaces, which is correct. The output looks correct!

One comment I might make is that there are two closing </jsp:root> tags.

Comment: @Josh Can you explain why you say, "The t:nameValuePair items do not have spaces, which is correct."  The nameValuePair tag specifies spaces within the <jsp:text>; should not those spaces be preserved?  If not, why not?

The two closing </jsp:root> tags is a copy/paste error on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like the tagx is being trimmed to make it simpler to write the tags. A new line in the end would for instance end up with a space where the tag is used and that might be bad.

Though why not put your text in the tag in a span:

```
<jsp:text><span> ${name}=${value} </span></jsp:text>
```

Or use the non breaking space: `&nbsp;`

This way you avoid the trim and you should get the result you want.

Comment: I actually want to emit HTML source with the tag, not renderable content.  As such, including a <span> element or an &nbsp; entity seems incorrect.

Comment: Then you should probably consider writing the tags without using jspx and do it using a class so you could control your output more. Though I wonder where you want to use the source? Is it for a save source I can understand that it is a problem, though if it is for displaying on the screen it might not matter.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with loosing whitespace, too. I am using jspx Documents and a pre compiler for production. But in my development machine I am using an embedded tomcat to recompile the jspx docs on the fly whenever the jsp is changing.

First I needed to achieve the same compilation results with the precompiler and the embedded tomcat compiler with this snippet for my `web.xml`

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
        <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

With this directive activated both behave the same. If you try to preserve whitespace **don't** do it like this:

```
<span class="ex1"> </span>
<span class="ex2"><jsp:text> </jsp:text></span>
<span class="ex3"> <jsp:text><!-- keep --> </jsp:text></span>
<span class="ex4"><!--  keep --></span>
<span class="ex5"><span> </span> <!--  keep --></span>
<span class="ex6">&#032;</span>
<span class="ex7">&#009;</span>
```

These are the only options which work for me:

```
<span class="ex8">&#160;</span>
<span class="ex9"><c:out value=" " /></span>
```

The Resulting jsp Compilation looks like this:

```
out.write("<span class=\"ex1\"/>");
out.write("<span class=\"ex2\">");
out.write("</span>");
out.write("<span class=\"ex3\">");
out.write("</span>");
out.write("<span class=\"ex4\">");
out.write("</span>");
out.write("<span class=\"ex5\">");
out.write("<span/>");
out.write("</span>");
out.write("<span class=\"ex6\"/>");
out.write("<span class=\"ex7\"/>");
out.write("<span class=\"ex8\">");
out.write(' ');
out.write("</span>");
out.write("<span class=\"ex9\">");
if (_jspx_meth_c_005fout_005f0(_jspx_th_ktr_005fform_005f0, _jspx_page_context))
  return true;
out.write("</span>");
```

By the way. You see the reference   which is a non-breaking space in XML which results in out.write(' '); in the compiled jsp. But the non-breaking space is preservered even if you don't see it. If you do a `hexdump -C test.jspx` you get:

```
6f 75 74 2e 77 72 69 74  65 28 27 c2 a0 27 29 3b  |out.write('..');|
```

".." in the right columns shows the non printable characters "c2 a0" which is unicode for "non breaking space".

As a non breaking space is not always what you want, your only option is `<c: out value=""/>`. If there are other options, I am happy to hear about it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

My text still had to break, so i added `<wbr>` before the spaces between the `${...}`s.

Turns out that doesn't work in Internet Explorer, and the problem was this line:

```
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
```

This fixed it:

```
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="false" %>
```